# How to find out what law firm submitted a granted patent?

Tags: attorney, documents, lawyers

Where on a granted US patent document, or in background information that I can look up using the patent number, can I find the name of the law firm that submitted the patent?
This is for an active patent so it's not that old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s on the face of the granted patent.
[image]

It could be the practitioner’s name or could be a firm. In the patent I highlighted it is the firm. If you looked in the file wrapper for the case in Patent Center you should see the various filings signed by John King who did a great job on this application.

It is also a searchable field in many search engines.

Comment: Thanks. In case it helps someone: the file wrapper can be accessed [here](https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/applications/). Search by the granted patent or patent application number, then when you find the patent of interest, click 'Address and Attorney/Agent Information'.